# C-R-A v4: How is the __WB_MANIFEST set? And is it customizable?

Tags: create-react-app, workbox

I am seeking to better understand PWAs with React, and one topic I am getting stuck on is the __WB_MANIFEST.

I've found that this is required by the Workbox CLI, and is used for precaching files, which is great. It defaults to containing the list of static files built by React, and that makes sense to me.

**But is this list customizable? What situations might I want to edit the C-R-A default value? And can I edit it in v4?**

Relevant C-R-A doc: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app/#customization

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's customizable, but not out-of-box in cra ([proposal](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5359), [unmerged PR](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/5369)). To config workbox without ejecting, you might want

[`react-app-rewired`](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired)

```js
// config-overrides.js
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  if (env === 'development') return config;

  const workboxConfig = config.plugins.slice(-1)[0].config;
  workboxConfig.exclude = [/.*\.txt/];
  // other config...
  return config;
};
```

Or [`customize-cra`](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra/blob/master/api.md#adjustworkboxfn):

```js
// config-overrides.js
module.exports = override(
  adjustWorkbox(wb =>
    Object.assign(wb, {
      exclude: (wb.exclude || []).concat("index.html")
      // other config...
    })
  );
);
```

> What situations might I want to edit the C-R-A default value?

Just as examples above, mostly, when you want to exclude something in precache manifest.

Comment: What's the downside of editing the `__WB_MANIFEST` value inside the `service-worker.js` file? Then i do not need these 2 libraries

Comment: `__WB_MANIFEST` is only used for `precacheAndRoute`. And I don't think there is any notable difference in terms of results. But editing `__WB_MANIFEST` in `service-worker.js` is somewhat "hacky" and indirect.